# MS Excel PERCENTILE and IF doesn't give correct result

Tags: excel

I am trying to get Percentile for selective data. Here in this example I am trying to get 10 percentile of scores where player name is a

Data :

```
      | A |  B
    ------------
     1| a |   1
     2| a |   2
     3| a |   3
     4| a |   4
     5| a |   5
     6| a |   6
     7| a |   7
     8| a |   8
     9| a |   9
    10| a |   10
    11| b |   11
    12| b |   12
    13| b |   13
    14| b |   14
    15| b |   15
    16| b |   16
    17| b |   17
    18| b |   18
    19| b |   19
    20| b |   20
```

Formula :

```
=PERCENTILE.EXC(IF(A:A="a",B:B,None),0.1)
```

Expected Output :

```
1.1
```

Actual Output :

```
2.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an *Array Formula* (aka CSE formula), so you should enter it then press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want a normal formula, use `Aggregate` which by nature handles arrays in a transparent way, with parameter `18` = `PERCENTILE.EXC`:

```
=AGGREGATE(18,6, B:B/(A:A="a"), 0.1)
```